# Angular and TS promise issue maybe?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

This code is returning before the server has a response. How do I get it to wait?

```
public loadDropBoxItemsFromServer(preventSaveToCache: boolean = false): Promise<IDropboxItems> {

    let hcpid = this.authService.getUserInfo().userId;

    this.log("Loading d-box from server");
    CredDropboxProvider._loadDropboxFromServerPromises = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(this.appSettingsService.getApiUrl(`/CredDoc/list/${hcpid}`), this.appSettingsService.getHttpRequestOptions(this.authService))
        .map((response: Response) => {
          this.log("Got a response");
          this.log(response.json());
          return response.json();
        })
        .timeoutWith(this.appSettingsService.defaultHttpTimeout, Observable.throw(new HttpTimeoutError(this.appSettingsService.timeoutErrorText)))
        .subscribe((dropbox: IDropboxItems) => {
          this.log("Dropbox loaded from server");
          if (!dropbox.items) {
            dropbox.items = []
          }
          if (preventSaveToCache) {
            CredDropboxProvider._loadDropboxFromServerPromises = null;
            resolve(dropbox);
          } else {
            CredDropboxProvider._loadDropboxFromServerPromises = this.saveDropboxToCache(dropbox)
              .then((newDropbox: IDropboxItems) => {
                this.log("New Dropbox");
                console.log(newDropbox);
                CredDropboxProvider._loadDropboxFromServerPromises = newDropbox;
                resolve(newDropbox);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                CredDropboxProvider._loadDropboxFromServerPromises = null;
                reject(error);
              });
          }
        },
          this.appSettingsService.buildStandardHttpErrorHandler(reject)
        );
    });
    console.log("Returning ");
      **THIS IS RETURNING NULL BECAUSE IT RETURNS BEFORE THE DATA IS RETURNED **
      return CredDropboxProvider._loadDropboxFromServerPromises[hcpid];
  }
```

THe above is in my provider and in my .ts file I am calling it:

```
this.CredDropBox.loadDropBoxItemsFromServer().then((db: IDropboxItems) => {
  console.log("Loading DB Items");
  console.log(db);
  this.dropbox = db; ** THIS IS ALWAYS UNDEFINED **
});
```

Comment: I would suggest using Observables instead. Then you can subscribe in the calling code and define code that runs only when the async process is complete.

Comment: First of all, your code looks too complex, you could try to simplify it first. Also, if you want to get the data at somewhere else (meaning this service will return it and some component will get it), then you should not `subscribe` to observables or you should not pass a function to `then` of the `Promise`. Just return the `Promise` or `Observable` and let other components do whatever they want with it.